# Is there a way in mongodb to group at multiple levels

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document which contains an array of array as given below.
This is the first document.

```js
{
  "_id": "5d932a2178fdfc4dc41d75da",
  "data": [
    {
      "nestedData": [
        {
          "_id": "5d932a2178fdfc4dc41d75e1",
          "name": "Special 1"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5d932a2178fdfc4dc41d75e0",
          "name": "Special 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to lookup(join) to another collection with the  _id in the nestedData array in the aggregation framework.

The 2nd document from which I need to lookup is

```js
{
  "_id": "5d8b1ac3b15bc72d154408e1",
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "rating": 4
}
```

I know I need to $unwind it twice to convert nestedData array into object.
But how do I group back again to form the same object like given below

```js
{
  "_id": "5d932a2178fdfc4dc41d75da",
  "data": [
    {
      "array": [
        {
          "_id": "5d932a2178fdfc4dc41d75e1",
          "name": "Special 1",
          "data": {
            "_id": "5d8b1ac3b15bc72d154408e1",
            "status": "COMPLETED",
            "rating": 4
          },
        {
          "_id": "5d932a2178fdfc4dc41d75e0",
          "name": "Special 2",
          "data": {
            "_id": "5d8b1ac3b15bc72d154408e0",
            "status": "COMPLETED",
            "rating": 4
          },
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please share both colloection with what you want collection

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar I have attached both the documents. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
db.testers.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'demo2',
        pipeline: [
            { $sort: {'_id': 1}},
        ],
        as: 'pointValue',
    }},
    {
       $addFields:{
            "data":{
                $map:{
                    "input":"$data",
                    "as":"doc",
                    "in":{
                        $mergeObjects:[
                            "$$doc",
                            {
                                "nestedData":{
                                    $map:{
                                        "input":"$$doc.nestedData",
                                        "as":"nestedData",
                                        "in":{
                                            $mergeObjects:[
                                               { $arrayElemAt: [  {
                                                     "$map": { 
                                                      "input": {
                                                                 "$filter": {
                                                                  "input": "$pointValue",
                                                                  "as": "sn",
                                                                  "cond": {
                                                                    "$and": [
                                                                      { "$eq": [ "$$sn._id", "$$nestedData._id" ] },
                                                                 ]
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                                      },"as": "data",
                                                      "in": {
                                                        "name": "$$nestedData.name",
                                                        "data":"$$data",
                                                      }}
                                                }, 0 ] },'$$nestedData'

                                            ],
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
     {$project: { pointValue: 0 } }
]).pretty()
```